# Powershell for text to CSV conversion is not working

Tags: powershell, csv, security

I created a little script to convert a specific txt structure to CSV. Input looks like this, always separated with dash line (no quotes), with both levels of text repeated any number of times:

"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

winlogon.exe pid: 880

Command line: winlogon.exe

Base                Size      Path

0x000000008a7c0000   0xb1000    C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe

Verified:    Microsoft Windows

Publisher:   Microsoft Corporation

Description: Windows Logon Application

Product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

Version: 10.0.15063.608

File version:    6.2.15063.608

Create time: Mon Sep 17 01:47:05 1979

0x000000005c830000  0x1db000  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

Verified:    Microsoft Windows

Publisher:   Microsoft Corporation

Description: NT Layer DLL

Product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

Version: 10.0.15063.608

File version:    6.2.15063.608

Create time: Wed May 11 01:39:23 203

"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

lsass.exe pid: 960

Command line: C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe

Base         Size         Path

0x00000000d2c30000  0x11000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe

Verified:    Microsoft Windows Publisher

Publisher:   Microsoft Corporation

Description: Local Security Authority Process

Product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

Version: 10.0.15063.483

File version:    6.2.15063.483

Create time: Thu Jan 09 08:26:10 2048

0x000000005c830000  0x1db000  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

Verified:    Microsoft Windows

Publisher:   Microsoft Corporation

Description: NT Layer DLL

Product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

Version: 10.0.15063.608

File version:    6.2.15063.608

Create time: Wed May 11 01:39:23 2039

My script is :

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\users\rummaan\Downloads\ListDlls\listdlls.txt") | 
Select-String -Pattern "(---------------------------------------...)[\s\S]*?(?=(---------------------------------------...)|($))" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value} | 
% { `
    @([PSCustomObject]@{
        "pid" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=pid: ).*?(?=\r)" |
 % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "Command_line" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=Command line: ).*?(?=\r)" |
 % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "BaseSizePath" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=Base                Size      Path ).*?(?=\r)" |
 % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
        "Verified" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=   Verified:   ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "Publisher" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=  Publisher:  ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "Description" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=    Description:    ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "Product" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=    Product:    ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "Version" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=    Version:    ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "File_version" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=   File version:   ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    "Create_time" = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "(?<=    Create time:    ).*?(?=\r)" | % {$_.Matches} | 
% {$_.Value};
    })} | 
Select-Object -Property pid,Command_line,BaseSizePath,Verified,Publisher,Description,Product,Version,File_version,Create_time | 
Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Rummaan\Downloads\ListDlls\listdlls.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What comes out is without subtext entries:
[enter image description here][2]

Could you please help me correct the script? I need a plain columnar flattened CSV, where columns would be all on the same level like: pid,command_line,base,size,path,verified,publisher,description,product,version,file_version,create_time.

Thank you!

Comment: Do not put links to pictures. Update your question with a short example of the data, and then what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

try this script:

```
#Create template for structure of cut
$template=@"
{Row*:"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
{Prog:lsass.exe} pid: {Pid:960}
Command line: {CommandLine:C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe}
Base Size Path
{BaseEXE:0x00000000d2c30000} {SizeEXE:0x11000} {PathEXE:C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe}
Verified: {VerifiedEXE:Microsoft Windows Publisher}
Publisher: {PublisherEXE:Microsoft Corporation}
Description: {DescriptionEXE:Local Security Authority Process}
Product: {ProductEXE:Microsoft® Windows® Operating System}
Version: {VersionEXE:10.0.15063.483}
File version: {FileVersionEXE:6.2.15063.483}
Create time: {CreateTimeEXE:Thu Jan 09 08:26:10 2048}
{BaseDLL:0x000000005c830000} {SizeDll:0x1db000} {PathDll:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll}
Verified: {VerifiedDLL:Microsoft Windows}
Publisher: {PublisherDLL:Microsoft Corporation}
Description: {DescriptionDLL:NT Layer DLL}
Product: {ProductDLL:Microsoft® Windows® Operating System}
Version: {VersionDLL:10.0.15063.608}
File version: {FileVersionDLL:6.2.15063.608}
Create time: {CreateTimeDLL:Wed May 11 01:39:23 2039}}
{Row*:"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
{Prog:lsass.exe} pid: {Pid:960}
Command line: {CommandLine:C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe}
Base Size Path
{BaseEXE:0x00000000d2c30000} {SizeEXE:0x11000} {PathEXE:C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe}
Verified: {VerifiedEXE:Microsoft Windows Publisher}
Publisher: {PublisherEXE:Microsoft Corporation}
Description: {DescriptionEXE:Local Security Authority Process}
Product: {ProductEXE:Microsoft® Windows® Operating System}
Version: {VersionEXE:10.0.15063.483}
File version: {FileVersionEXE:6.2.15063.483}
Create time: {CreateTimeEXE:Thu Jan 09 08:26:10 2048}
{BaseDLL:0x000000005c830000} {SizeDll:0x1db000} {PathDll:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll}
Verified: {VerifiedDLL:Microsoft Windows}
Publisher: {PublisherDLL:Microsoft Corporation}
Description: {DescriptionDLL:NT Layer DLL}
Product: {ProductDLL:Microsoft® Windows® Operating System}
Version: {VersionDLL:10.0.15063.608}
File version: {FileVersionDLL:6.2.15063.608}
Create time: {CreateTimeDLL:Wed May 11 01:39:23 2039}}
"@


#explode data
$AllRow=gc "C:\temp\test.txt" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template 

#get all properties of object 'Row'
$AllProperties=($AllRow.Row | gm | where MemberType -eq "NoteProperty").Name

#Build properties for select
$props = @()
foreach ($field in $AllProperties) { 
    $props += @{n="$field";e=([Scriptblock]::Create("`$_.Row.$field"))}
}

#Select all properties and export to CSV
$AllRow | select $props | export-csv "c:\temp\resul.csv" -notype
```

Comment: Seems to get stuck on gm:                                                                                                                gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At C:\Users\Rummaan\Downloads\ListDlls\listdllsScript1.ps1:50 char:31
+ $AllProperties=($AllRow.Row | gm | where MemberType -eq "NoteProperty ...
+                               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand